# Best way to implement on-button feedback

Tags: angularjs

I'd like the buttons in my app to give feedback, as for example [demonstrated here](http://lab.hakim.se/ladda/).

I'm wondering how I should structure my code. I want to be able to change the classes, the text and maybe disable them upon click. I guess a directive is the right fit, but the exact changes that will happen depend upon the button, and putting content or class names inside a controller or directive doesn't seem very right.

Right now i have a very generic directive that takes all options through additional attributes, but I wonder if someone can see a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always start with a very simple `directive` and extend with CSS classes. If you want to do a particular work well anything you can use a function of the `controller`. I think you made ​​the right choice. Think to look angular UI for best practice : http://angular-ui.github.io

You can add event on each action:

```
// Create a new instance of ladda for the specified button
var l = Ladda.create( document.querySelector( '.my-button' ) );
// Start loading
l.start();
// Will display a progress bar for 50% of the button width
l.setProgress( 0.5 );
// Stop loading
l.stop();
// Toggle between loading/not loading states
l.toggle();
// Check the current state
l.isLoading();
```

Comment: Alright, thank you :). I'll take a loot at angular-ui to see how they manage this kind of things.